# Pandas - OverflowError : Python int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python, pandas, overflow

```
Data = pd.read_csv(file)
```

I'm getting overflow error:python int too large to convert to C long, while read a csv file of 6.25GB.

Working fine with files less than 2GB.

Answer (score 0):

How much RAM does your computer have? If I'm not mistaken, pandas uses RAM to convert CSVs to data frames, so if you have less than 6gb RAM that might be the problem.

Comment: I have 16GB ram and 125GB empty storage space.

Comment: Well in that case, I would just split the CSV into 3-4 different CSVs, read them, and then combine them using pd.concat() since you said reading smaller CSVs works